# Run After A Certain Column is Filled

Tags: excel, vba

For example I have cells A1,B1,C1. A1 and B1 are empty and C has a formula = A1+B1. I would like to do is that C1 will add A1 + B1 once B1 is no longer empty.

In reality, there would be D1,E1,F1 ... so forth with formulas as well. I can put the formulas inside a Workbook_change routine, but it would be very buggy if you do a copy and paste. I was wondering if there is another way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA. In C1 you can enter this formula:

`=IF(AND(LEN(A1)>0,LEN(B1)>0),A1+B1,"")`